# Java/LibGDX get sprite from userdata

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to access a sprite from a fixtures userdata which should work fine, but gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.freeranger.colorcourse.entities.EvilE
at com.freeranger.colorcourse.handlers.MyContactListener.beginContact(MyContactListener.java:74)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.beginContact(World.java:985)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(Native Method)
at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:689)
at com.freeranger.colorcourse.screens.Play.update(Play.java:185)
at com.freeranger.colorcourse.screens.Play.render(Play.java:202)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.freeranger.colorcourse.Main.render(Main.java:139)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

The code that causes the problem is this one:

```
String[] data = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "pink", "orange_gravity_block"};
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(fa.getUserData() != null && fa.getUserData().equals(data[i])){
            if (fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("evile_left_sensor")) {
                ((EvilE)fb.getUserData()).reverseVelocity(); //this causes error
            }else if (fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("evile_right_sensor")) {
                ((EvilE)fb.getUserData()).reverseVelocity(); //this causes error
            }
        }   
    }
```

In my Play class this code sets the userdata to the Evil-E (enemy):

```
 EvilE c = new EvilE(body, game);
 eviles.add(c);
 body.setUserData(c);
```

The collision all happens in my Contact Listener and the enemy I'm trying to access (EvilE) is in my Play class(PlayScreen).

What's expected is for my enemies to change direction when they hit a wall, but they don't - instead the game crashes and I get the error I showed before. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting EvilE object into the userdata

```
 EvilE c = new EvilE(body, game);
 eviles.add(c);
 body.setUserData(c); // c is an EvilE object
```

And here you are expecting to get a String:

```
fa.getUserData().equals(data[i]) //fa.getUserData() is EvilE and data[i] is a String
```

here you are trying compare `EvilE` object to String object on equality. At some point  down into `EvilE.equals` method `String` is casted into `EvileE` type and that's why you are getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

**EDIT**

You can add property into EvilE object e.g. `String status` and compare by this property. e.g. `((EvilE)fa.getUserData()).getStatus().equals(data[i])`

Comment: Thank you, but how do I go about fixing the problem now that I got this information? I guess this means I need an alternative way to compare userdata, but I can't come up with one...

Comment: if you got EvilE which can be "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "pink". just compare with this property. so `((EvilE)fa.getUserData()).getColor().equals(data[i])` should work

Comment: So, I realized this code needs a bit of explaination: The strings inside data are all the kinds of blocks the evil-e can collide with. If fa equals one of them and fb equals one of the evil-e sensors the evil-e should change direction/reverse velocity.

Comment: Now I see. so in any case you need some flag into your EvilE class which will change according the collision than you will be able to compare it with other strings.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is the code inside the fb if-statement is executed but throws an error, the ClassCastException one. That one doesn't seem to be comparable with a string..

Comment: yes that's why you need a String property into your class to compare with. ok If you have some kind of collision you can save some data into EevilE.activeSensor string property. e.g. `evilE.setActiveSensor("evile_right_sensor")` then you will check that `((EvilE)fb.getUserData()).getActiveSensor().equals("evile_right_sensor")`

Comment: I tried doing this: `if (((EvilE)fb.getUserData()).getActiveSensor().equals("evile_right_sensor")) {
      ((EvilE)fb.getUserData()).reverseVelocity();
     }` But that just gave me the error inside the if. The getActiveSensor is returning a String.

Comment: I figured what's giving me the error is when I'm trying to cast the fb.getUserData() to EvilE. And I have no idea how to solve that one...

Comment: just print fb.getClass() and fa.getClass() and show me. because from your snippet of code it's very hard to figure out what  really  happens there

Comment: Both of them print out `class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture`

Comment: sorry can you print  fb.getUserData().getClass() and fa.getUserData().getClass()

Comment: both print out `class java.lang.String`

Comment: check this answer this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860019/contact-listener-not-working-in-libgdx

Comment: Thanks, so now this part is working: 
`if (fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("evile_left_sensor")) {
    ((EvilE)fb.getUserData()).reverseVelocity(); // but this line gives me an error
}`

Comment: Oh I found the problem, I had to access fixture.getbody.getuserdata() instead!